# top users -> comments -> php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a users table and a comments table and i want select from users the top users that have the big amount of comments from the comments table and order them by numbers of comments

table structure

users

```
id | username | password
```

comments

```
id | text | author_username
```

Comment: The comments table should be joined by `author_userid` and not `author_username` Poor form.

Comment: Also ensure that your `id` columns are primary keys so that they are indexed to facilitate faster querying.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following MySQL statement to list the users with the most comments. `CommentCount` tells you the number of comments made by a particular user.

```
SELECT
  users.username,
  COUNT(comments.id) AS CommentCount
FROM
  users
  INNER JOIN comments ON users.id = comments.author_userid
GROUP BY
  users.username
ORDER BY
  COUNT(comments.id) DESC
```

Please note that you will have to change `author_userid` into `author_username` first!

Comment: Top clause doesn't exist on mysql.

Comment: You're dead right! I corrected it now. If you'd only like to know the top 10 users, just add `LIMIT 10` to your MySQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

My SQL is a bit rusty, but something like this should give you what you're looking for (although as I mentioned, the user ID should be the only user identifier in the `comments` table.)

```
Select count(id), author_username from comments group by author_username
```

Comment: and how can I display the count in php?

Comment: I usually work with ODBC, so I'm also not familiar with the `mysql` syntax. If you don't know how to read a field from a database, that should be your first question, instead of how to form the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select u.username,count(c.comments) as total
    from users as u
    left join comments as c
    on u.username = c.author_username
    group by u.username
    order by total desc
```

I would change join field as dutchie432 suggested. Add a limit clause in order to have your desired number of records.